# Contador hacia atrás en Segundos

Tags: javascript

En el proyecto que estoy realizando en mi web que es que los niños aprendan a sumar jugando, estoy teniendo la idea de crear Juegos de mates básicos.

Consultando con amigos un amigo mío me ha pasado la cuenta atras debido a que lo jeugos que quiero hacer van con una cuenta atrás de tiempo.
Este es el código pero creo que hay alguna manera mucho más sencilla de hacerlo, ya que hay lineas de código que no se que hacen.

```
var seconds = 5; 
function secondPassed() { 
  var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30)/60); 
  var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60; 
  if (remainingSeconds < 10) { 
    remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds; 
  } 
  document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" +     remainingSeconds; 
  if (seconds == 0) { 
    clearInterval(countdownTimer); 
    alert('SE ACABAO'); 
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Buzz Buzz"; 
  } else { 
    seconds--; 
  } 
} 

var countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000);
```

Las Lineas de código que no entiendo son las siguientes:

```
var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30)/60); 
var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60; 
if (remainingSeconds < 10) { 
  remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds; 
}
```

He preguntado en el Chat y me han dicho que seguro que se puede simplificar la cuenta hacía atrás.

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

```
var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30)/60);
```

Para mostrar los minutos restantes, necesitas dividir entre 60 los segundos totales. Ejemplo: 80 segundos / 60 = 1,33 minutos.

Como sólamente te interesa mostar los minutos (obviando el ,33), lo que hace es un Math.round(). De este modo, 1,33 pasaría a ser 1.

Math.round() redondea, por lo que si tuviesemos 105 segundos = 1,75 minutos, devolvería como resultado un 2 (Y 2 minutos sería algo incorrecto). Es por esto que está restando 30 a los segundos, para redondear a la baja y obtener siempre los minutos correctos.

Esto sería menos lioso con un trunc: `var minutes = Math.trunc(seconds/60);`

```
var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
```

% devuelve el resto obtenido de la división. Ejemplo: 100 segundos % 60 = 40. De este modo muestras sólo los segundos (los minutos ya los hemos sacado antes).

```
if (remainingSeconds < 10) { 
remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds; 
}
```

Es un formateo estético. Cuando los segundos fuesen menores a 10, (2 minutos y 5 segundos por ejemplo) estaríamos mostrando algo como esto: 2:5.

El código añade un 0 por delante a los segundos para que aparezca del siguiente modo: 2:05

Quitando el formateo de texto y muestra por pantalla, tu código de cuenta atrás es así de simple:

```
var seconds = 5; 
function secondPassed() { 
    seconds--; 
} 

var countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000);
```

Comment: Pero proque entonces la varaible seconds es 5 y se lo resta a 30? No sería más fácil evitarse todo esto y decir que segundos es 30 y que cuente ya desde cero?

Comment: Lo ideal sería truncar el valor, de este modo no tendrías que restar 30 segundos jugando con el round. `Math.trunc(seconds/60)`

Comment: a que te refieres con Truncar? No sería más fácil coger una variable de 30 e ir restando 1 cada segundo?

Comment: Eso ya lo está haciendo. Sea 30, 80 o 160... La resta cada segundo funciona bien.

Comment: Vale, a ver si me explico, si yo ahora quiero subir el tiempo de 30 a 45 como lo haría? sigo sin entender esas lineas aunque la explicación esta bien

Comment: El tiempo inicial es 5, no 30. Tendrías que cambiar 5 a 45 si lo que quieres es empezar en 45 segundos.

Comment: Tal y como esta programado ahora el contador empieza a descontar en 30 segundos es eso lo que no entiendo.

Comment: El código que muestras arriba el contador empieza en 5 segundos.

Comment: no el contador empieza en 30 segundos ya que en el juego empieza en 30 segundos es eso lo que no entiendo

Comment: Eso míralo en tu código del juego. Ya que este comienza en 5. Mira el ejemplo de @Pablo Lozano y verás que cambiando el 5 por 65 la cuenta atrás empieza en 65.

Comment: Y como que en mi juego empieza en 30?

Comment: Pues eso digo, que tendrás que mirarlo en tu código del juego. Dudo que este sea el código completo. En algún lugar se estará estableciendo la variable a 30.

Answer (score 1):

El código que te han pasado funciona correctamente y la parte que no entiendes es la que formatea el tiempo restante para indicarlo en minutos y segundos: Mira lo que pasa si la variable seconds supera los 59 segundos

```js
var seconds = 65; //número de segundos a contar
function secondPassed() {

  var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30)/60); //calcula el número de minutos
  var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60; //calcula los segundos
  //si los segundos usan sólo un dígito, añadimos un cero a la izq
  if (remainingSeconds < 10) { 
    remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds; 
  } 
  document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" +     remainingSeconds; 
  if (seconds == 0) { 
    clearInterval(countdownTimer); 
    alert('Se acabó el tiempo'); 
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Buzz Buzz"; 
  } else { 
    seconds--; 
  } 
} 

var countdownTimer = setInterval(secondPassed, 1000);
```

```html
<label id="countdown"></label>
```

No me parece una buena idea pasar a `setInterval` un string para llamar a la función en lugar de la función, pero por lo demás funciona bien.

`Math.round(num)` redondea el número, con lo que tenemos que, si el tiempo es más de 30 segundos, en minutos será 0.5 o más... lo que al redondear lo deja en 1. Al restarle 30 lo que hace es asegurarse de que el redondeo siempre es hacia abajo. Pongo unos ejemplos:

- Tenemos 65 segundos, por lo que queremos mostrar `1:05`

65 / 60 = 1.08 -> un minuto y algo, se redondea a 1 (no haría falta restarle 30)

De todos modos, si restamos 30 tenemos:
35 / 60 = 0.58 -> Se redondea a 1 porque es el entero más cercano.

- Tenemos 115 segundos, por lo que queremos mostrar `1:55`:

115/60=1.91 -> se redondearía a 2, pero al restarle 30 pasa a ser 1

Pero podemos usar `Math.trunc(seconds/60)` en lugar de round, que dejaría el código más claro:

```js
var seconds = 65; //número de segundos a contar
function secondPassed() {

  var minutes = Math.trunc(seconds/60); //calcula el número de minutos
  var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60; //calcula los segundos restantes
  //si los segundos usan sólo un dígito, añadimos un cero a la izq
  if (remainingSeconds < 10) { 
    remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds; 
  } 
  document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" +     remainingSeconds; 
  if (seconds == 0) { 
    clearInterval(countdownTimer); 
    alert('Se acabó el tiempo'); 
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Buzz Buzz"; 
  } else { 
    seconds--; 
  } 
} 

var countdownTimer = setInterval(secondPassed, 1000);
```

```html
<label id="countdown"></label>
```

Comment: Si no digo que no funcione se que funciona, pero creo que es bastante complejo no? y porque le resta 5 al 30?

Comment: La resta es al reves, resta 30 al 5. El motivo de la resta ya está explicado, es para que el redondeo muestre los minutos correctos.

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Aunque las dos respuestas anteriores creo que explican muy bien el código del contador (que era lo que se preguntaba), sí me gustaría apuntar que no me parece buena idea llevar la cuenta de segundos en función del número de veces que se llama la función del `setInterval`.

Establecer un `setInterval` con 1000 milisegundos no garantiza que la función se vaya a llamar exactamente cada segundo por lo que la cuenta no sería exacta. Yo calcularía el tiempo restante basándome en el reloj interno del equipo para poder ser más exactos.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de cómo podrías hacerlo:

```js
var seconds= 70;

// Calcula la fecha de finalización del contador sumando
// el número de segundos a la fecha actual
var end = (new Date()).getTime() + seconds * 1000;
displayCounter();
var timeout = setInterval(displayCounter, 300);

function displayCounter(){
  // Calcula el número de segundos que faltan para llegar a la fecha de finalización
  var counter = Math.floor((end - (new Date()).getTime()) / 1000);
  if (counter < 0) counter = 0;
  
  document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 
      Math.floor(counter / 60) + ':' +
      ('00' + Math.floor(counter % 60)).slice(-2)
      
  if (counter === 0) clearTimeout(timeout);
}
```

```html
<label id="countdown"></label>
```

De paso también tienes otra forma de visualizar los segundos restantes.

Comment: Gracias Asier, esto va a una web, no se si funcionaria pero necesito contador de 30 s

Comment: Para que el contador sea de 30s no tienes más que cambiar el 70 por un 30.

Comment: Vale, y me puedes explicar un poco lo que hace el código? que coge la fecha del pc?

Comment: Le he añadido algún comentario. Básicamente calcula la fecha de finalización del contador sumándole a la fecha actual el nº de segundos que se quieren contar. Luego, en cada interacción, resta de la fecha de finalización la fecha actual para saber cuantos segundos faltan para que acabe la cuenta, y éste es el resultado que muestra.

Comment: `Math.floor((end - (new Date()).getTime()) / 1000)` resta de la fecha de finalización la fecha actual que devuelve el nº de milisegundos que faltan, lo divide entre 1000 y con `Math.floor` elimina los decimales.

Answer (score -1):

Es muy sencillo:

```
    let tiempo = 60000
    const elem = document.getElementById('countdown')

    let cuentaAtras = minutos => { 

      tiempo *= minutos
      let tiempoActualizado = tiempo
      let m = 0 
      let s = 0

      let cronometro = setInterval( () => { 

        tiempoActualizado -= 1000
        m = Math.trunc(tiempoActualizado / 60000)
        s = Math.trunc(tiempoActualizado / 1000)
        elem.textContent = `Quedan ${m} minutos y ${s} segundos.`

        if (tiempoActualizado === 0) { 
          alert('¡Su tiempo ha terminado!')
          clearInterval(cronometro)
        }

      }, 1000)

    }

cuentaAtras(3) // 3 minutos de ejemplo, siempre expresado en minutos. Por ejemplo: 30 segundos = 0.3 minutos.
```

Comment: Incluso podrías pasar los minutos que quedan para un momento en el futuro: